# Есть ли разница между указателем с крышкой и указателем без нее, на что это влияет?

Tags: delphi, указатели

Заметил такую особенность компилятора, что разницы между указателем с крышкой и указателем без нее вообще никакой нет, а все нормально работает в обоих случаях. На что это вообще влияет (скрины ниже)? Здесь, `pCurr` - указатель на элемент-запись.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Постарайтесь забыть про указатели. Рекорды, классы - да. Дженериковские - тем более. Указатели - нет. А так - ничем не отличается, если не указывать крышку - компилятор сам неявно сделает это. Но так было не всегда :)

Comment: @kami Благодарю за объяснение :)

Comment: @kami чем вам не угодили указатели в Делфе?

Comment: @Kromster Слишком много с ними проблем от непонимания правил работы. Для связи с WinApi - да, без них никуда. В остальном...самое распространенное - хранение в нетипизированных контейнерах, некорректное кастование, высвобождение только указателя (а-ля `Dispose(untypedPointerOfTypedVar)`... Даже если разработчик сам работает с ними корректно, то в 99% случаев те, кто копирует его подход - выдадут плохой код, с memleak и AV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компилятор Делфи достаточно умен, чтобы автоматически делать приведение указателя в подобных случаях (т.к. тут нету неоднозначности в том что имеется ввиду). Обычно, это достаточно удобно.